# I want make this sentence natural, "you can reference this site"

Tags: grammaticality, reference

My situation is that I have a site link(like this stackexchange), and I want to announce this site link for anyone who visit my web-site as a reference.

is this natural expression?

> If you need more information, you can reference this site : [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)

If this is not a natural expression(sentence), could you amend it?

thanks

Comment: You can _visit_ this site or _consult_ this site.

Comment: "You can _refer to_" would make more sense

Answer (score -1):

*Reference* in the verb form, as you intend to do, is inaccurate. The example sentence you've used would mean that you are soliciting people to list the website as source of reference. Since you desire people to *consult* your website, the verb *visit* , though over-used, is not a bad choice. Other good choices would be: *"explore"*, *"peruse"*, *"examine"* etc.